# Windows extended attribute to determine where file was downloaded from?

Tags: windows-10

I wish to determine where the file was downloaded from if it was downloaded. MacOS has a very neat `Where from` attribute that tells you exactly that. How do I do this on Windows 10? Looking for Windows API solution or a C# script to access said data.

I downloaded a file on Windows, transferred it to mac and it did not have "Where from" attribute. [This post](https://superuser.com/questions/396692/what-are-these-extended-attributes-eas-in-the-files-in-windows-8/396720#396720) hints that Windows does know if the file was downloaded but does not say if it is a true/false value or does it include URL.

Comment: If downloaded via Firefox or IE then you can get the information from the browser (provided it hasn't been (permanently) deleted). It's not attached to the downloaded file though. See [Windows Forensic Analysis (pdf)](https://www.sans.org/security-resources/posters/windows-forensic-analysis/170/download) for more information.

Comment: The "hint" you are referring to is the Zone.Identifier  - which only tells you what internet zone it was downloaded from (trusted, internet or untrusted). It's only available for browser downloads to an NTFS disk.

Comment: As far as I know there is no source information stored when files are downloaded using other software, for example ftp, sftp, curl, etc ..

Comment: So, in a very limited specific set of circumstances, you can probably write a program to gather the required information and attached it to a downloaded files alternate data stream, but help with writing such a program is off topic for [su].

Comment: If you tell us **why** you need this information we might be able to suggest some alternatives ...

Comment: @DavidPostill My intention was to write a sorting script that would put downloaded files in predetermined folders. Not by file extension but by where the files are from. Email attachments in one, ebooks in another etc… Very simple to do on mac, sadly complicated on Windows.